# Iptables massive 1:1 NAT

Tags: iptables, nat

I have to connect two LANs: LAN1: 10.10.0.0/16 and LAN2: 192.168.0.0/16.
I can't do simple routing, because 192.168.0.0/16 net is prohibited in LAN1, so I am thinking of using Full cone nat (1:1) to translate 192.168.x.y/16 to 10.11.x.y/16. Each translation is done by this rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.11.0.0/16 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.0/16
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to-source 10.11.0.0/16
```

But I will have to enter 254*254*2 rules, what will, I think, result in enormous performance degradation. So, is there a way to write such one-to-one translation with minimum number of rules?

Comment: Why can't you just route between the two networks???

Comment: BECAUSE(second line): I can't do simple routing, because 192.168.0.0/16 net is prohibited in LAN1

Answer (score 17):

I am not sure if it is present in all kernels, but what you may be looking for is the **NETMAP** target.

From the [iptables man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables)

```
NETMAP
 This target allows you to statically map a whole network of 
 addresses onto another network of addresses. It can only be 
 used from rules in the nat table. 

 --to address[/mask]
     Network address to map to. The resulting address will be 
     constructed in the following way: All 'one' bits in the 
     mask are filled in from the new 'address'. All bits that 
     are zero in the mask are filled in from the original 
     address.
```

Answer (score 9):

Like the first answer said, use -j NETMAP:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.11.0.0/16 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.0.0/16
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j NETMAP --to 10.11.0.0/16
```

It's probably a good idea to add -d 10.10.0.0/16 in the POSTROUTING row as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a small shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=0 ; $i<256 ; i=$i+1 )) ; do
  for (( j=0 ; $j<256 ; j=$j+1 )) ; do
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.11.$i.$j/16 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.$i.$j/16
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.$i.$j/16 -j SNAT --to-source 10.11.$i.$j/16
  done
done
```

But I think thereis an error. I think it should be /32 and not /16.

Comment: /32, I have already done that but I want to find a more beautiful way, than 254*254*2 rules