# NETMAP in iptables,

Tags: firewall, iptables, nat

I need to know the general usage of NETMAP which is used in iptables command(linux's debian OS). 
Is NETMAP used in place of other NAT such as SNAT or DNAT or MASQ ????

What is the relation of NETMAP to firewall??

Regards

Sanket

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/109569/iptables-massive-11-nat

Answer (score 4):

NETMAP is a NAT target like SNAT or DNAT, but not MASQ.  NETMAP builds a big one-to-one translation for an entire subnet.

```
iptables -v -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 10.1.2.0/24
# translations.
192.168.1.0/24 - 10.1.2.0/24
192.168.1.1    - 10.1.2.1
192.168.1.2    - 10.1.2.2
192.168.1.3    - 10.1.2.3
192.168.1....  - 10.1.2....
192.168.1.255  - 10.1.2.255
```