# What router will support a block of public IP addresses

Tags: router

Does anyone know what/if any routers support a block of multiple public IP addresses? Is this possible to do WITHOUT using 1 to 1 NAT?  Basically I want to be able to forward any public IP:Port to any local IP:Port

public -> local

1.1.1.1:100 -> 192.168.1.5:100

1.1.1.1:101 -> 192.168.1.6:101

1.1.1.2:100 -> 192.168.1.7:100

1.1.1.2:102 -> 192.168.1.5:102

I have a Cisco RV180W but its awful and horribly buggy.  The only way I can get it to recognize multiple public IPs is via 1 to 1 Nat, port forwarding was broken in general until a recent firmware release and even the most recent firmware has glaring bugs regarding firewall access rules noted in the "Known Issues" of the release notes.

I'd just like to replace the router, but with limited networking knowledge I'm finding it difficult to figure out what/if this configuration is supported.

Comment: Get a Linux or [PFsense](http://www.pfsense.org/) based router.  They offer you flexibility.  In any case, translating one address to another IS one-to-one NAT.  Even if you are able to implement it using a single statement (eg iptables netmap http://serverfault.com/questions/109569/iptables-massive-11-nat).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the majority of professional-grade routers support multiple IP addresses on one NIC and can use NAT with them.  However, it sounds like you might be trying to use a home "router" in a professional environment.  I'd advise you to not do that (but installing DD-WRT, if you are up for an adventure, might extend your capabilities and will certainly give you the benefit of iptables).

No consumer-grade stuff will support this for you by default, and the type of gear you have (while marketed as professional) is not much different.

If you are doing something even remotely complicated, you should look into getting some real network hardware.  That said, even a linux PC with two NICs in it running iptables would be an improvement.

Comment: This is supposedly a "small business" router. Ironically, I've found that "consumer" routers often work better than these...

Comment: Can you recommend a router?

Comment: Yes, I googled it and saw, shed a tear, and tore up one of my old cisco certificates ;)

Comment: No, I can't recommend a specific one.  Something that isn't a router/wireless AP/switch combination might be a good start - it's always good to seperate these functions out.